# bash export expression without expanding?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I want to do the following

`export LOGS=//server/log_files/2014_*/server_{1,2,3}`

so I can do something like

`grep 'Exception' $LOGS/log.txt`

I tried alias as well, but I can't get it to not expand.

How could I do this?

Comment: yes, but then when I try `ls $LOGS/log.txt` i get "cannot access //server/log_files/2014_*/server_{1,2,3}/log.txt: No such file or directory"

Comment: It is saving it as un-expanded (when I quote it) but it won't expand when I try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `export`, right hand side of an assignment doesn't go through path nor brace expansion.

With `export`, though, brace expansion is performed. You can prevent it by quoting the value:

```
export LOGS='//server/log_files/2014_*/server_{1,2,3}'
```

If you want to use such a value, though, you have to use `eval`:

```
eval grep 'Exception' $LOGS/log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in the case where you want extended globs. That's the cleanest and the most semantically correct here, as you want to match filenames. As I'm overly pedantic, I'd argue that brace expansions are not the right tool for your task.

```
# This defines a string that will glob
# No pathname expansions are performed at this step
logs_glob='//server/log_files/2014_*/server_@(1|2|3)'

# You need to activate extended globs with extglob
# To have a failure when no files match the glob, you need failglob
shopt -s failglob extglob

# Unquoted variable $logs_glob, as pathname expansion is desirable
grep 'Exception' $logs_glob
```

Some will argue that with glob techniques you can't properly handle spaces in names. In fact, you have two ways: either use `?` as a wildcard (this will match *any* character, hence spaces in particular) or use the character class `[[:space:]]`. This character class will match any space (regular spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.)

---

Another technique is to use arrays, still with extended globs. I'd argue that this is cleaner.

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

# This will populate array with all matching filenames.
# If no matches, array is empty (since we shopted nullglob)
logs_array=( //server/log_files/2014_*/server_@(1|2|3) )

# Before you launch you command with the array, make sure it's not empty:
if ((${#logs_array[@]}!=0)); then
    # Observe the quotes for the expansion of the array
    grep 'Exception' "${logs_array[@]}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about extended globs.  Although I tried it on cygwin and it hangs on the grep command (or even just `ls $logs_glob`).

Comment: @anthonybell what version of Bash?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin) on Windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: @anthonybell: check that extglobs do work on cygwin. The test is simple: in a scratch directory `scratch_dir`: `touch test_{a..z}; shopt -s extglob; echo test_@(a|b|c|d)` should output `test_a test_b test_c test_d` and also try it from the parent dir: `cd ..; echo scratch_dir/test_@(a|b|c|d)` . If this works, all is good. What does the leading `//` mean in cygwin?

Comment: Yes, that worked.  The `//server` is for a networked directory in windows.

Comment: @anthonybell try extended globs with leading `//`. Maybe that's why you got the shell hang on you: it can't deal properly with extended globs and networked directory (I actually have no idea). By the way, extended globs are not necessary here, you may replace them by standard globs: `ls //server/log_files/2014_*/server_[123]`. If this works then we're good `:)`.